# Optimizing Concurrent User Performance in Blazor Server Applications without Increasing Costs"

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

We've developed an enterprise solution using Blazor Server. However, we've encountered issues because Blazor Server relies on SignalR for communication with the DOM. Specifically, we're experiencing difficulties when multiple users concurrently access the application, causing a slowdown. If we go for azure signalr service, cost is shooting very high, Is there any suggestions, where we can use the same application work accurately with some fixes.

Comment: It sounds like your project is flawed in its design, please enable the logging to check what happened when multiple users concurrently access the application.